# How to install features in an installer based on license/price model?

Tags: windows, installation, wix

guys, I'm not sure the title is correct on my real problem. I am now having a requirement to deliver one windows installer which should contains all features or functionalities, but the customers can only install a sub set of the features or functionalities based on which he buys. And it also allows him to buy more features (or functionalities) if he pays.

I am using wixtoolset to create the kit. However, the term 'feature' I used above does not necessarily mean the term "feature" in wixtoolset context. I just don't know how to describe my requirement more precisely.

The reason is, the software we are developing actually provide many functionalities, but different customers don't want all of them, so this would be a way for them to save money. We cannot deliver specific features/functionalies for different customers otherwise it'll be a nightmare for us to manage.

I would appreciate if anybody could assist.

Comment: One approach is to install everything and then unlock features via the license key. That way the application itself does all the work and your setup can be kept simpler. It is very costly to fail deployment, so this approach is better than it might appear at first. Application features are easier to update, manage and debug. Also: single source advantage.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul, thanks for your help. Your approach is ok for me. Could you share me more details how to use license key to lock or unlock features? Is there any pattern or example that I can learn?

Comment: Preventing installation would also be pointless, because users with lesser licenses can just COPY the files from the full-license users. The check should be in the program itself. You can start with any software protection/monetization toolkit (like for example once famous HASP keys, they changed brand name now though) - and learn from their documentation/tutorials. Would you in the end buy their tools or other tools or try to create your own one (better not, but your choice) - the general how-to knowledge you can learn from those tutorials of any vendor.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_copy_protection_schemes